# Bootstrap pill content not going away

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's pill nav bar and for some reason once I add my code which contains tiles that give a netflix feel (on the STEMuli tab), the navbar will no longer remove the content when going to another tab. It actually will add the next tabs information directly below. I thought I was missing some div tags, but I took away some code and rebuilt it to double check, div tags checkout. I am not sure what could cause this? Because right when I remove the content in my "STEMuli" tab in the actual code and just add some plain text it works just fine, even if I add a row to it...I am stuck please help!

```css
.popover-header{
  color:#000000;
}
#row{
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo{
  z-index:0;
}

.row {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
.row__inner {
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.tile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
          transform-origin: center left;
}
.tile__img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
}
.tile__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0,0,0,0.9)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.9) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 450ms opacity;
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}
.tile__details:after,
.tile__details:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: #000;
}

.tile__details:before {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.tile:hover .tile__details {
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
.row__inner:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
}
.row__inner:hover .tile {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}
.tile:hover ~ .tile {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
}
a:hover{
  color: #F1D302;
}
.checkbox-wrapper {
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
}
.btn{
  background-color: #F1D302;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;

}
.card-img-top {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}

.btn-xlong {
    padding: 10px 50px;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
       -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
}
.steps-form-3 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 470px;
  position: relative; }
  .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column; }
    .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3:before {
      top: 14px;
      bottom: 0;
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      width: 2px;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: #7283a7; }
    .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 {
      height: 150px;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3.no-height {
        height: 50px; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 p {
        margin-top: 0.5rem; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 button[disabled] {
        opacity: 1 !important;
        filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important; }
      .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 {
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border: 2px solid #59698D;
        background-color: white !important;
        color: #59698D !important;
        border-radius: 50%;
        padding: 18px 18px 15px 15px;
        margin-top: -22px; }
        .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3:hover {
          border: 2px solid #4285F4;
          color: #4285F4 !important;
          background-color: white !important; }
        .steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 .fa {
          font-size: 1.7rem; }
::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width: 0px;
  height:5px;
  background-color: #161925;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color: #F1D302;
  border-radius:10px;
  box-shadow: insert 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.spacing{
  padding: 6px;
}
/*This css file defines the color scheme and font of all of the webpages so import into every new webpage*/

body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #9E2B25;
  color:#FDFFFC;
}
h4{
  color:#FDFFFC;
}
.button{
    background-color:#0267C1;
}
.nav-pills .nav-link.active
{
  background-color: #0267c1;

}
h3{
    color: #ffffff;
}
#cardimg
{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <title>STEMuli</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="/js/moment.js"></script>


</head>
<script>
  (function() {
    ('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
  })
</script>

<body>

  <!--This is where the logo is-->

    <div id="row" class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
      <img src="/img/tcb-logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-STEM" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true"><h3>STEMuli</h3></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-Community" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false"><h3>Community</h3></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-aboutUs" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false"><h3>Who We Are</h3></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-STEM" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
<div class="row">
  <h2>Credit</h2>
    <div class="row__inner">
      <a onclick="redirectbankon()">
        <div class="tile" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="Description" data-content="The Bank On It module provides an overview of banking services and is designed to help participants build a positive relationship with a financial institution.">
          <div class="tile__media">
            <img class="tile__img" src="/img/bankonit.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="tile__details">
            <div class="tile__title">
              <h5>Bank On It</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
          <div class="tile__media">
            <img class="tile__img" src="/img/borrowing.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="tile__details">
            <div class="tile__title">
              <h5>Borrowing Basics</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
          <div class="tile__media">
            <img class="tile__img" src="/img/keepitsafe.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="tile__details">
            <div class="tile__title">
              <h5>Keep it Safe</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
          <div class="tile__media">
            <img class="tile__img" src="/img/checkitoutpt1.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="tile__details">
            <div class="tile__title">
              <h5>Check It Out</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
          <div class="tile__media">
            <img class="tile__img" src="/img/yourownhome.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="tile__details">
            <div class="tile__title">
              <h5>Your Own Home</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-Community" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">How are you</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-aboutUs" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">.</div>
    </div>


  </main>

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
  <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/form.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of invalid HTML markup, somewhere unclosed tags and an unknown `</main>` tag in the end before the body, an unclosed `<a href='#.' onclick="redirectbankon()">` which is wrapping the nested `div.tile` which is ok if you are using `HTML5` but you still need to close it. A better way would be to provide an `id` to the anchor and then bind the `click` event to the anchor to call the function on click.

Remove the flaws in your HTML and it will work correctly by replacing the content rather than adding the tab underneath the first.

See a demo below of your code.

```css
.popover-header {
  color: #000000;
}

#row {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.logo {
  z-index: 0;
}

.row {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.row__inner {
  -webkit-transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms -webkit-transform;
  transition: 450ms transform;
  transition: 450ms transform, 450ms -webkit-transform;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.tile {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: 450ms all;
  transition: 450ms all;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.tile__img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.tile__details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  -webkit-transition: 450ms opacity;
  transition: 450ms opacity;
}

.tile__details:after,
.tile__details:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: #000;
}

.tile__details:before {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: 7px;
  margin-top: -18px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.tile:hover .tile__details {
  opacity: 1;
}

.tile__title {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.row__inner:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-62.5px, 0, 0);
}

.row__inner:hover .tile {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.row__inner:hover .tile:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  opacity: 1;
}

.tile:hover~.tile {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(125px, 0, 0);
}

a:hover {
  color: #F1D302;
}

.checkbox-wrapper {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #F1D302;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
}

.card-img-top {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn-xlong {
  padding: 10px 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: normal;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.steps-form-3 {
  width: 2px;
  height: 470px;
  position: relative;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3:before {
  top: 14px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #7283a7;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 {
  height: 150px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3.no-height {
  height: 50px;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 p {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 button[disabled] {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid #59698D;
  background-color: white !important;
  color: #59698D !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 18px 18px 15px 15px;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3:hover {
  border: 2px solid #4285F4;
  color: #4285F4 !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

.steps-form-3 .steps-row-3 .steps-step-3 .btn-circle-3 .fa {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #161925;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #F1D302;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: insert 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

.spacing {
  padding: 6px;
}


/*This css file defines the color scheme and font of all of the webpages so import into every new webpage*/

body {
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  background-color: #9E2B25;
  color: #FDFFFC;
}

h4 {
  color: #FDFFFC;
}

.button {
  background-color: #0267C1;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #0267c1;
}

h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

#cardimg {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title>STEMuli</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:500" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/mastercss.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/profile.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="/js/moment.js"></script>


</head>
<script>
    (function () {
        ('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
</script>

<body>

    <!--This is where the logo is-->

    <div id="row" class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
        <img src="/img/tcb-logo.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3 justify-content-center" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-STEM" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home"
                aria-selected="true">
                <h3>STEMuli</h3>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-Community" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile"
                aria-selected="false">
                <h3>Community</h3>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-aboutUs" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact"
                aria-selected="false">
                <h3>Who We Are</h3>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-STEM" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Credit</h2>
                <div class="row__inner">
                    <a href='#.' onclick="redirectbankon()">
                        <div class="tile" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="Description"
                            data-content="The Bank On It module provides an overview of banking services and is designed to help participants build a positive relationship with a financial institution.">
                            <div class="tile__media">
                                <img class="tile__img" src="/img/bankonit.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile__details">
                                <div class="tile__title">
                                    <h5>Bank On It</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="tile__media">
                                <img class="tile__img" src="/img/borrowing.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile__details">
                                <div class="tile__title">
                                    <h5>Borrowing Basics</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="tile__media">
                                <img class="tile__img" src="/img/keepitsafe.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile__details">
                                <div class="tile__title">
                                    <h5>Keep it Safe</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="tile__media">
                                <img class="tile__img" src="/img/checkitoutpt1.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile__details">
                                <div class="tile__title">
                                    <h5>Check It Out</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="tile__media">
                                <img class="tile__img" src="/img/yourownhome.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="tile__details">
                                <div class="tile__title">
                                    <h5>Your Own Home</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-Community" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">How are you</div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-aboutUs" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">.</div>
    </div>




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="/js/form.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback it helped a lot!

Comment: is there a tool to help me identify unclosed tags? Or is just a matter of brute forcing through it?

Comment: @wadeaston you should use some editor like [**`Visual studio code`**](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or atom these editors help you identify quickly